# Борьба с нехорошими символами в именах файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x, хеширование

Уважаемые форумчане! Требуется ваша помощь!

Хочу разобраться с файловым хранилищем, **удалить дубликаты файлов**. Написал программу обходящую дерево директорий. Застрял на этапе вычисления хэшей, дело в том, что **имена файлов содержат** не только алфавитные символы и цифры, а также **пробелы и спецсимволы**. Сначала Python останавливался на первом же проблемном файле, позже я дописал try / except, и теперь он доходит до конца, пропуская проблемные файлы, но меня это не устраивает!

Язык: **Python 3**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

try:
    hash = subprocess.check_output('md5sum -- "{}"'.format(file), universal_newlines=True, shell=True)[:32]

except Exception:
    print('Проблемный файл {}'.format(file))
```

С *hashlib* пока не получается, проблем много создаёт, поэтому пока пришлось воспользоваться стандартной утилитой *md5sum*. Может подскажете заодно как решить проблему с применением *hashlib*.

Comment: Зачем вы считаете хэши внешней программой, когда у питона есть модуль для их вычисления? Почему бы вам не задать вопросы, описывающие ваши «проблем много создаёт» с hashlib?

Comment: @andreymal, не получается пока с hashlib, могу ошибаться, но мне показалось что суммы не те получаются, может я неправильно что-то делаю, да и проблема с символами там острее стоит как мне показалось. Python строже к ошибкам

Comment: Вы бы показали как вы делаете-то, у меня он ни разу не считал неправильно и ни к каким символам не придирался. Вон в ответе например вполне рабочий вариант

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы пользуетесь сторонними программами через консоль там, где следует пользоваться полноценными библиотеками (стандартной библиотекой в данном случае), которые работают *через API операционной системы*, а поэтому не имеют проблем со спецсимволами, с которыми в консоли работать невыносимо сложно (это известная Ахиллесова пята консоли).

Для подсчёта MD5 есть [hashlib.md5()](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html). Подсчитать хэш файла можно следующим образом (из [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3431838)):

```
def md5(fname):
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
            hash_md5.update(chunk)
    return hash_md5.hexdigest()
```

Comment: b"" - это опечатка? Не совсем понимаю зачем частями читать файл

Comment: @tonchikp затем, что теоретически файл может оказаться и размером в сотни гигабайт, например. Вы сможете его прочитать в оперативную память не частями, целиком? :) `b""` — нет, не опечатка.

Comment: @andreymal, вообще-то да, что-то я не подумал об этом, согласен с Вами! А что тогда делает b"" ? и для чего лямбда? Честно говоря я долго программировал на других языках и после них мне пока кажется такое диким, сначала подключаешь библиотеку, что увеличивает название функции (метода), потом файл с подстраховкой несуществования (with), потом читать кусочками (что правильно, не спорю), плюс обновлять сумму, и после всего этого ещё и отступы. Слишком многословно как-то, не привык я ещё

Comment: @tonchikp распихивание функций по модулям — хорошо и правильно, позволяет не превращать пространство имён в груду хлама и не загружать лишнее. `with` используется для того, чтобы автоматически закрыть файл после того, как этот самый with закончится: если бы вы заменили это на что-то вроде `f = open(fname, "rb")`, вы могли бы забыть вызвать `f.close()` или он сам бы не вызвался, если бы возникла ошибка где-то выше по коду, и файл остался бы незакрытым. При чтении ничего страшного, но при записи файл, который забыли закрыть, может создать большие проблемы, поэтому with это хорошо и правильно.

Comment: @tonchikp В этом коде сокращения кода в питоновском духе. Вместо with, for, iter, lambda можно использовать старый-добрый while и вручную вызывать close. Суть в том, что читаются последовательности байтов (бинарные строки в версии 3.0), пока не будет возвращена пустая последовательность; тогда чтение прекращается и файл закрывается.

Comment: @tonchikp `iter` вызывает функцию из первого аргумента до тех пор, пока она не вернёт значение из второго аргумента. Здесь вызывается `f.read(4096)` (через лямбду, по-другому никак) до тех пор, пока она не вернёт пустые байты (`b""`) вместо содержимого файла — это означает, что весь файл прочитан и цикл можно прервать. Многословность — следствие надёжности: в принципе весь код можно записать в одну строку `return hashlib.md5(open(fname, "rb").read()).hexdigest()`, но тогда будут проблемы с большими файлами и опять же файл остаётся открытым и помечен в ОС как занятый.

Comment: andreymal, Squidward, огромное вам спасибо что подробно и терпеливо всё разъяснили, это очень ценно для меня, спасибо!

Comment: @tonchikp это самое распросранененное неправильное суждение которое я слышал. GC удалит обьект файла, а файл.__del__ его закроет. with конструкция нужна по большей части для явного указание области работы с файлом.

Comment: @AndrioSkur, ничего себе, не знал об этом! А почему он так делает? Разве open не только для работы с файлами?

Comment: open только для работы с файлами. A with явного указания области в которой достпен обьект. "А почему он так делает?" ну для удобства, чтоб не писать везде with или close. Это же питон а не С.

Comment: Сделал немножко по своему:
    def md5_file(file):
        md5 = hashlib.md5()
        with open(file, mode='rb') as file2:

            for part in file2.read(4096):
                md5.update(part)

        return md5.hexdigest()

Пробовал с mode='rb', выдаёт:

    TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required

Пробовал с mode='r', выдаёт:

    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 66: invalid start byte

Подскажите пожалуйста что не так? (Python3)